# Javascript - redistribute weight proportionally if a weight has been removed

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a set of data that listed the proportion of a test that contributed to the final grade. If a student missed a/some tests, the weight will be redistributed proportionally among the tests he has taken. I would like to calculate the new proportion for those tests that a student has taken. How can I compare an array to an array of objects to determine which test a student was absented? As for the calculation for the revised proportion, I was thinking of using an `if` statement, can anyone think of a more efficient way to achieve this? Thank you!

```
testPercentage = {"A":0.5,"B":0.3,"C":0.15,"D":0.05};
maryTest = ["A", "B"];

revised test percentage for Mary would now be:
A = 0.5/(1-0.15-0.05)
B = 0.3/(1-0.15-0.05)


if (maryTest.length == 1){
//assume Mary has only written test A
    A = 1
}
if (maryTest.length == 2){
    A = 0.5 + (0.5/(1-the proportion of those two tests she has missed))
    B = 0.3 + (0.3/(1-the proportion of those two tests she has missed))
}
if (maryTest.length == 3){
//
}
if (maryTest.length == 4){
// same as testPercentage 
}
```

Comment: Do the values of testPercentage always total up to 1?

Comment: Is this pseudocode or actual?

Comment: @samanime yeah you're right I just edited the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a math problem than programming. Not that complicated.

I think your formula is wrong. Revised A should be `0.5 / 0.8`, not `0.5 + 0.5 / 0.8` which is greater than 1.

```js
var testPercentage = {"A":0.5,"B":0.3,"C":0.15,"D":0.05};
var maryTest = ["A", "B"];

var maryWeights = maryTest.map(key => [key, testPercentage[key]]) // [ ["A", 0.5], ["B", 0.3] ]
var totalWeight = maryWeights.map(entry => entry[1]).reduce((a, b) => a + b) // 0.8

var revisedTestWeights = Object.fromEntries(maryWeights.map(([key, value])=> [key, value / totalWeight]))
```

Comment: Thank you I will test it out! And yes you're right and I just updated the post.